# How to Fix Poor Performance on Filter By Text

Tags: performance, jquery

A while back I found some code that allows you to filter the contents of a SELECT by typing in a text element.  It works well however, over time the performance degrades pretty badly.  I'm not sure if it is the filter code or the way in which I am activating it.

The SELECT shows up in a modal dialog (bootstrap) so I have the following code:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  $(".focusable").val("").focus();
  var select = $('#myModal').find(".modal-body").find("select");
  var text = $('#myModal').find(".modal-body").find("input[type='text']");
  select.filterByText(text, true);
});
```

And here is the filter code:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function (textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
  return this.each(function () {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function () {
      options.push({value:$(this).val(), text:$(this).text(), data:$(this).data("short-name")});
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);
    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function () {
      var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search, 'gi');

      $.each(options, function (i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          var copyOption = $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value);
          copyOption.data("short-name", option.data);
          $(select).append(copyOption);
        }
      });
      if (selectSingleMatch === true &&
          $(select).children().length === 1) {
        $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Can anyone shed some light on where my performance issue(s) might be and how to solve it?

Comment: on change and keyup all the code is executed? so doing RegExp and DOM operations on every change is quite inperformant... how about a little delayed solution that works after stop typing?

Comment: I understand how that could effect performance, but this is more of a performance over time issue. Not an out of the gate performance issue.  It actually works quite well the first few times the dialog is shown.

Comment: do you reset the content of the modal window when it is closed? if not it keeps all the listeners... just an idea...

Comment: Only to the extent that the textfield is cleared out which resets the filter on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading through the comments I would suggest to add the following:

```
$(textbox).bind('change keyup', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  // your code
});
```

Is the event triggered more than once on a single keyup after some times the dialog is shown?

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  $('#myModal').find(".modal-body").find("input[type='text']").off("change keyup");
});
```

Comment: I think this is probably going to tell me what I need to know.  I'll report back after some testing.  Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have to use .unbind() instead of .off(), depends on the jQuery version you are using